# Customizing presentation template

Tags: beamer, templates, presentations

I was searching for some presentation templates and found this:
https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59b82451befd3747d21dd824

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[
%%% options passed to the outer theme
%    progressstyle=fixedCircCnt,   %either fixedCircCnt, movCircCnt, or corner
%    rotationcw,          % change the rotation direction from counter-clockwise to clockwise
%    shownavsym          % show the navigation symbols
  ]{AAUsimple}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}

% colored hyperlinks
\newcommand{\chref}[2]{%
  \href{#1}{{\usebeamercolor[bg]{AAUsimple}#2}}%
}

\title{The AAU Simple Beamer Theme}

\subtitle{v.\ 1.2.1}  % could also be a conference name

\date{\today}

\author{
  Jesper Kjær Nielsen\\
  \href{mailto:jkn@es.aau.dk}{{\tt jkn@es.aau.dk}}
}

\institute[

  Dept.\ of Electronic Systems\\
  Aalborg University\\
  Denmark
] % optional - is placed in the bottom of the sidebar on every slide
{% is placed on the bottom of the title page
  Department of Electronic Systems\\
  Aalborg University\\
  Denmark

  %there must be an empty line above this line - otherwise some unwanted space is added between the university and the country (I do not know why;( )
}

% specify a logo on the titlepage (you can specify additional logos an include them in 
% institute command below
\pgfdeclareimage[height=1.5cm]{titlepagelogo}{AAUgraphics/aau_logo_new} % placed on the title page
%\pgfdeclareimage[height=1.5cm]{titlepagelogo2}{AAUgraphics/aau_logo_new} % placed on the title page
\titlegraphic{% is placed on the bottom of the title page
  \pgfuseimage{titlepagelogo}
%  \hspace{1cm}\pgfuseimage{titlepagelogo2}
}

\begin{document}
% the titlepage
{\aauwavesbg%
\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering] % the plain option removes the header from the title page
  \titlepage
\end{frame}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \end{document}*
```

My question is: How can I customize that .tex code to use the logo of a different institute ?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Your link just gives "Restricted, sorry you don't have permission to load this page." It would be much better if you could make a question that does not rely on external sites.

Comment: The page gives the message : Restricted, sorry you don't have permission to load this page. May be you have not the right to do that... It depends on the license of the template and because Of the error it gives I suppose it is not a free one.

Comment: Apologies. I've edited with the preamble.

Comment: Actually, it's just a template from sharelatex. I believe it could be edited.

Comment: we still cannot access the template...

Comment: On the official website of the AAUsimple theme (http://kom.aau.dk/~jkn/latex/latex.php) it says "If you like the AAU Simple theme, but are not affiliated with Aalborg University, I recommend that you have a look at the Aalborg theme instead"

Comment: It's all right then. It seems a nice template. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the official website of the AAUsimple theme ([kom.aau.dk/~jkn/latex/latex.php](http://kom.aau.dk/~jkn/latex/latex.php)) it says:

> If you like the AAU Simple theme, but are not affiliated with Aalborg University, I recommend that you have a look at the Aalborg theme instead

For the `Aalborg` the logo can be specified using beamers `\logo` command.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Aalborg}

\logo{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It still gives an error saying "! LaTeX Error: File `beamerthemeAalborg.sty' not found."

Comment: @Fib1123 You'll need the theme (.zip is downloadable from the website I linked to in my answer) and follow the installation instructions in `aalborgtheme.pdf`(which is also in the .zip file)